# how to restore mysql database from a .sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a testDBbackup.sql file. I dropped the mysql database a while back and I was wondering how I could restore it from my backup file. I am using a Mac. I was hoping somebody could show me how to do it from the command line, unless there is an easier way from the file system or something.

Comment: Also I'm just using a localhost server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your file contains the database create code and that is not conflicting with existing databases. Just go with.

```
mysql -u root -p
-- You'll be prompted for password
mysql> source filename.sql
```

If database with a given name already exists and you only want to dump data into it via terminal.

```
mysql -u root -p testdb < filename.sql
-- You'll be prompted for password
```

If you have to create it and then dump

```
mysql -u root -p
-- You'll be prompted for password
mysql> create database test;
mysql> source filename.sql
```

Make sure you replace `root` with your actual user, `testdb` with your database name and `filename` with actual file.

Answer (score 1):

On your localhost server find `phpmyadmin`.

1. Generate an empty database
2. Perform import from your testDBbackup.sql file

Note that if `testDBbackup.sql` is large you can ZIP it.